# Is possible to have bar chart with stacking option plus overlay feature along in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have plotted chart bars as Stacked, but overlapped one on another. but only last two series need to overlap, not first one. First series(additional income) need to be plot as same as `'stacked : "normal"'` do.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJpCk/4/) to explain my experiment with highchart.

Is there any option for Series object to achieve that?

[image: This is what I trying to do]

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You should disable gruping or set pointWidth http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth